# Use PostgreSQL xpath function and get the first returned value from the array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, xpath

Generally speaking:  if a PostgreSQL function returns an array, can I access one of its enumerated values without having to make a subquery?

Specifically, here is an abstracted example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
    xpath('/a/text()', subquery.xmlvalue)
FROM (
    SELECT '<a>theValue</a>'::xml xmlvalue
) subquery ;
```

…which returns an array:

```
   xpath    
------------
 {theValue}
(1 row)
```

…but what I want is the first (and only, in this case) value from this array:

```
   xpath    
------------
 theValue
(1 row)
```

…so, my question is, is this (below—a subquery) the only way to do it, or is there a way to do it without `subquery2`?

```
SELECT subquery2.xpatharray[1] FROM (
    SELECT
        xpath('/a/text()', subquery.xmlvalue) xpatharray
    FROM (
        SELECT '<a>theValue</a>'::xml xmlvalue
    ) subquery
) subquery2 ;
```

…because this does **NOT** work:

```
SELECT
    xpath('/a/text()', subquery.xmlvalue)[1]
FROM (
    SELECT '<a>theValue</a>'::xml xmlvalue
) subquery ;
```

…and the error message is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 2:         xpath('/a/text()', subquery.xmlvalue)[1]
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I feel silly… but since answering one's own question is allowed and encouraged on this site…

All you have to do is put the `xpath` function in another set of parentheses:

```
SELECT
    (xpath('/a/text()', subquery.xmlvalue))[1]
FROM (
    SELECT '<a>theValue</a>'::xml xmlvalue
) subquery ;
```

Comment: It says I can accept my own answer in 2 days; it may be longer than that until I can get back to this, but I'll come back and select an answer (mine or someone else's) later.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer! This is quite a trick. I hope somebody can explain why the parens are necessary